# Apache Kafka 2.12-1.1.0 not working with JDK -10.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka

Why doesn't Apache Kafka 2.12-1.1.0 work with JDK 10.0.1?

```
./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties 
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
/..../kafka_2.12-1.1.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 252: [[: 10 2018-04-17: syntax error in expression (error token is "2018-04-17")
[0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/..../kafka_2.12-1.1.0/bin/../logs/zookeeper-gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: This is answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970622/kafka-unrecognized-vm-option-printgcdatestamps

Answer (score 15):

Changing the `bin/kafka-run-class.sh` with below code did the magic:

In Line #251

Before:

```
JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version "([^.-]*).*"/\1/p')
```

After:

```
JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version "([^.-]*).*/\1/p')
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the offending logging option KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS for java 10 from the file kafka-run-class.sh

from

KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=100M"

to

KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails"

Answer (score 2):

> JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version
>   "([0-9]*).*$/\1/p')

This line solved my problem with openjdk!

This is the original line from bin/kafka-run-class.sh that you need replace:

> JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version
>   "([^.-]*).*"/\1/p')

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade your java version from java 8, you have to sync with version upgrade.

Replace **KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS** value in your kafka-run-class.sh with the below code.

```
if [[ "$JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION" -ge "9" ]] ; then
    KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xlog:gc*:file=$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M"
else
    KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS="-Xloggc:$LOG_DIR/$GC_LOG_FILE_NAME -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails"
fi
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the regex used for identifying the java version in the `bin/kafka-run-class.sh` especially if you are using openjdk.

You can replace `line 255` in the `bin/kafka-run-class.sh` with :
`JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -E -n 's/.* version "([0-9]*).*$/\1/p')`

as in https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L286

Answer (score 0):

Above all answers are from the shell script point of view. If some people are using a bat file on the windows machine below answer will be helpful.

### Windows Bat file

Go to `..\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\bin\windows` and search for `kafka-run-class.bat` file

Go to Line Number 158 and set the JDK Path.

```
IF ["%JAVA_HOME%"] EQU [""] (
    set JAVA=java
) ELSE (
    set JAVA="..\Java\jdk12\bin\java"
)
```

### Shell Script

Go to `..\kafka_2.12-2.2.0\bin\` and search for `kafka-run-class.sh` file.
and then search for $JAVA_HOME and go this line update your JDK path accordingly.

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA="java"
else
  JAVA="$JAVA_HOME\java"
fi

JAVA = "../Java/jdk12/bin/java"
echo $JAVA
```

I think this will address the issue. This will occur when we have multiple JDK installed on our machine and want to test the things.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the tags like PrintGCDateStamps,UseGCLogFileRotation from **line 314**